# Is it haram for women to use steel blades to shave hair?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, women, hair

There is a concept among muslim women that they cannot use steel blades for removing hair, some might say it is haram. So even removing hair is painful e.g through waxing is it fine unless it is not steal.  Is it true if so any documentation of it?

Comment: @UmH Steel. sorry my mistake. yes metal alloy

Comment: @UmH I am asking, not "pluck", more like shave like a razor blade.

Answer (score 1):

Removal of hair in armpits and pubic area is part of natural disposition (fitrah) in Islam for males and females.

It can be done by

- plucking,
- Using a depilatory agent,
- shaving
- cutting

Use of metal based alloys in form of razors is totally accepted.

Head shaving, eyebrow plucking for females is forbidden.

Only Allah can make things/actions lawful/unlawful. There is nothing in revelation which tells use of metal razors is forbidden to remove armpit or pubic hair in case of women

Comment: But is there any saying about it as there is about men from wearing gold and silk. A reference will be useful.

Comment: Answer edited,  please see

Answer (score 1):

I could not find any indication suggesting that shaving with a metal blade is *haram* for women. But some madhabs do consider it *recommended* for women to pluck pubic hair (or to use chemical hair removal) rather than shaving with a blade.

> لا خلاف بين الفقهاء في جواز إزالة شعر العانة بأي مزيل من حلق وقص ونتف ونورة (٢) ، لأن أصل السنة يتأدى بالإزالة بأي مزيل (٣) ، كما أنه لا خلاف بينهم في أن الحلق أفضل لإزالة شعر العانة في حق الرجل (٤) .أما المرأة فيرى الحنفية والشافعية أن الأولى في حقها النتف (٥) .وذهب جمهور المالكية والنووي في قول إلى ترجيح الحلق في حق المرأة (٦) ، لحديث جابر في النهي عن طروق النساء ليلا حتى تمتشط الشعثة وتستحد المغيبة (٧) .قال الحنابلة: لا بأس بالإزالة بأي شيء ويؤخذ من عباراتهم أنهم يرون أفضلية الحلق (١) .
>
> There is agreement among the jurists on the permissibility of removing pubic hair by any method such as shaving, trimming, plucking or using a chemical. That is because the purpose of the Sunnah is satisfied with any method of removal.
>
> And there is agreement that for men the recommended method of removing pubic hair is shaving.
>
> As for women: The stance of the Hanafis and Shafi'is is that it is better to pluck the hair. The stance of the majority of the Malikis and one saying of Nawawi is that shaving is preferred for women as well - because of the [hadith](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5246) of Jabir which tells men to not go to their wives at night on return from a journey, so that their wives may comb their hair and *shave* their pubes. The Hanbalis say:  It is alright to remove hair by any method, although shaving is better.
>
> <sup>— [Mawsoo‘ah al-Fiqhiyyah  29/234-235](https://shamela.ws/book/11430/18495#p1)</sup>